# DateTime JodaTime conversion

Tags: date, datetime, timezone, jodatime

Please imagine the following:

I've this date in the Azores (GMT -1)
 23/10/2010 23:00:00

And i want to convert this date to the following (the GMT +1)

24/10/2010 01:00:00

I want this behavior for any date in any timezone and the Date function with timezone give me the GMT -1 for this case.

Please note that i'm using JodaTime.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(2010, 10, 23, 23, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeZone.forOffsetHours(-1));  // (GMT -1) 23/10/2010 23:00:00 
  DateTime inAnotheTimeZone = dateTime.withZone(DateTimeZone.forOffsetHours(1));
```